# Regardings Gtk, is it possible to disable accelerators while writing in an entry?

Tags: c, gtk

I'm modifying an existing program wrote in `C` in which I added a `GtkEntry`.
When I try to write, for example, `"qwerty"` in the `entry`, it's filled only with `"qwrty"` because the character `"e"` is used as a shortcut (`accelerator`) to call another `function`, and that function is also activated when `"e"` is pressed.

Is there any way to avoid `accelerator callbacks` while we are writing in the `entry`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can `disconnect` your accelerator group in the `focus-in-event` callback of `GtkEntry`, and connect it again when you focus back out of the entry. Here's an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

GtkAccelGroup *accel_group;
GClosure *closure;

void accelerator_pressed(void)
{
    printf("Accelerator pressed!\n");
}

gboolean focus_in_callback(void)
{
    gtk_accel_group_disconnect(accel_group, closure);
    g_closure_unref(closure);
    return GDK_EVENT_PROPAGATE;
}
gboolean focus_out_callback(void)
{
    closure = g_cclosure_new(accelerator_pressed, 0, 0);
    gtk_accel_group_connect(accel_group, GDK_KEY_e, (GdkModifierType)0, GTK_ACCEL_VISIBLE, closure);
    return GDK_EVENT_PROPAGATE;
}

int main()
{
    gtk_init(NULL, NULL);

    GtkWidget *window, *box, *entry, *button;

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    box = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 5);
    entry = gtk_entry_new();
    button = gtk_button_new_with_label("click me");

    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), GTK_WIDGET(entry), TRUE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), GTK_WIDGET(button), TRUE, TRUE, 0);

    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(GTK_WIDGET(entry), "focus-in-event", G_CALLBACK(focus_in_callback), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(GTK_WIDGET(entry), "focus-out-event", G_CALLBACK(focus_out_callback), accel_group);

    accel_group = gtk_accel_group_new();
    gtk_window_add_accel_group(GTK_WINDOW(window), accel_group);

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), box);
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    gtk_main();
}
```

Comment: Is this the only possibility? Looks like a lot overhead. Isn't there any way to prioritize local key-events over global ones?